# Can a superuser cancel (not delete) meeting created by other user?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm developing an automatic meeting cancellation. I have a Superuser that can cancel meetings which were created in the name of a meeting room. But this Superuser can't cancel meeting created from the name of a simple employee.

I'm using Exchange 2010.

I tried do cancel meeting using impersonation, but still received errors. There were 2 types of errors:

1. Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
2. User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action

I do a request as a superuser:

```xml
...
<soap:Body>
 <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendOnly">
  <m:Items>
   <t:CancelCalendarItem>
      ...
   </t:CancelCalendarItem>
...
```

I receive a response:

```xml
...
<m:ResponseMessages>
  <m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
    <m:MessageText>User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action.</m:MessageText>
...
```

I expect that Superuser could cancel a meeting, organized by an employee.
Is it possible? If it is, than what permission must Superuser be granted?

Answer (score 0):

The only person that can cancel a Meeting is the Organizer (which is why you get the error that you do). If you have EWS Impersonation rights then you will need to impersonate the Organizer and then Cancel the copy of the Appointment that is in the Organizer mailbox. You can't use the instance of the appointment from an attendee or Meeting room.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Glen.

Is it posible to write a script that we can use to impersonate the organizator and then to revert back? So that the app will do this actions in background

Comment: As long as the Organizer is Internal eg within your exchange org and you have impersonation rights. Then you should be able to grab the Organizer email address impersonate them to access their mailbox and master copy of the appointment and then do you you require.